# Subclassing FrameworkElement in Silverlight 4.0 - A Measure Pass Question

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, measureoverride, frameworkelement

I currently have an issue in Silverlight where I want to detect the change in size for an element, and react to it.  However, listening with `.SizeChanged` is actually not sufficient, as often I get a flash of the element at the size it's changing to, before the functionality in the `.SizeChanged` is called.  So I have perhaps a two-fold question.

My intention is to use the Measure pass to calculate the manipulations I want to apply *before* the size is visually changed, so that I can eliminate this flickering effect.  As far as I'm aware, the only way to do this successfully is to create a UIElement that does these calculations on the Measure pass, before Measuring the rest of these elements.

As such, I was hoping to create a really light UIElement by extending off FrameworkElement.  **However**, I can't get the stupid thing to display anything.  I'm under the impression that at the FrameworkElement level, a subclass would require adding the content to the VisualTree and I can't seem to work out how to do that.

I was hoping to avoid extending off `UserControl`, or `Panel`, as they are far heavier than what I need, with so much extra functionality I dont want.  I merely want to catch the Measure pass and perform some work there.

So, is it possible to extended off `FrameworkElement` in Silverlight 4.0 and *actually render something*?  If not, is it possible to listen for/interrupt the measure pass another way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manually add content to the visual tree - this functionality is only exposed to built-in Silverlight controls.

In such a situation, you should derive from `Control` and specify a default template for this control to use - in the default template, specify the desired contents of the visual tree.

To allow a default template to be used, you should specify `DefaultStyleKey` in your contructor and give it the value of your control type. E.g. `DefaultStyleKey = GetType()`.

Then, you can specify a style such as this, in e.g. `Themes/Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="my:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:MyControl">
                <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Or if your control is a content-presenting control, just derive from `ContentControl` and it takes care of all the plumbing - you just need to set `Content` to whatever you wish to display and your subclass will only need to perform the measure-pass override logic.

Comment: Apologies, I don't know why I had `ContentControl` and `Border` as the two classes to extend off in the description.  As I said, I'm merely trying to get in on the Measure pass early, such that I can do the calculations *before* the visual change.
While I appreciate your answer as another option to consider, it seems to again be a far heavier solution than what I need.  Perhaps I'm treating memory/processing power as far more precious than it is, but I'm still hoping for a lighter solution.